# how to modify every point in Postgis geometry?

Tags: postgis

I need to do some transform on Postgis geometry, saying turn `wgs84` into `gcj02`, I can use `ST_DumpPoints` to get all the points, but after modifying them, it seems not an easy and elegant way to join them back. I tried `ST_Collect`, it's not taking the `path` from `ST_DumpPoints`.

Comment: Why don't you use ST_Transform for the original geometry?

Comment: `st_transform` supports some standard `proj4` supported codes, like `epsg:4326` to `epsg:3857`, but in China transforming from `epsg4326` to `gcj02`, is not included.

Comment: What about extending proj with gcj02? If you can solve the transformation, then you know all the necessary parameters for proj.